# Angularjs dropdown Options to show current selected item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

What I want to accomplish here is when user gets into the application the selectedLocal is already set to ID 184 and Name A Name instead of the default name.

Any help is appreciated.

I have the following script:

```
 function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.User = [{
            ID: 109,
            Name: 'A Name'
        }, {
            ID: 161,
            Name: 'B Name'
        }, {
            ID: 184,
            Name: 'C Name'
        }];

        $scope.selectedLocal = [{ID: 184,Name: 'A Name'}]

    }
```

and the following html:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>{{selectedLocal}}</div>
    <select ng-model="selectedLocal" ng-options="item.Name for item in User" ng-change="localSelectChange()">
        <option value="">Default</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here is the js fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/hamsaya/mmwy0aeo/)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that `ng-options` compares the option values with the `ng-model` value *by reference*. That means that at some point there's a 
loop that compares `$scope.User[i] === $scope.selectedLocal` where `i` is a value between 0 and `$scope.User.length`.

So you need to initialize `$scope.selectedLocal` with a reference from `$scope.User`.
In your case that would be `$scope.selectedLocal = $scope.User[2];`.

Or you could do this:

`ng-options="item.ID as item.Name for item in User"`

and

`$scope.selectedLocal = 184;`

Depending on the context one solution might be preferred over the other.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I am new to angularjs but what an amazing library. I used knowckoutjs before and I am liking this better :)

accepting the answer.